# Tema wordpress quebrado após migração

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Fiz a migração de um site wordpress para outro servidor. Utilizei o plugin Duplicator, que ja tenho um pouco de experiencia e consegui fazer a migração com todos os usuários, posts (Como já era esperado). Na hora de carregar a pagina, painel admin ou qualquer configuração ele carrega apenas uma mensagem de erro: "This WordPress Theme requires PHP7+, Node8+ and MariaDB". Mesmo com estes softwares instalados no novo servidor não tive nenhum sucesso para fazer o site rodar.

Trocando o tema para outro qualquer (diretamente pelo DB, pois o wp-admin também gera erro) o site funciona.

Procurei nos arquivos do site e do tema aonde essa mensagem de erro era gerada, não encontrei nenhum resultado.

Comment: E como garantiu que está utilizando o PHP 7+?

Comment: php --version
PHP 7.3.7 (cli) (built: Jul  3 2019 14:34:15) ( NTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.7, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies